# Swift hide UITextField

Tags: cocoa-touch, swift, ios8, uitextfield

I've got a UIPageViewController set up with 4 pages, each one with a different title. I also have a UITextField in the pageContentViewController that I would like to be able to hide based on what the title is. I've got this:

```
class pageContentViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

  @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var textEntry: UITextField!

  var pageIndex: Int = 0
  var titleText = "default"

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  textEntry.delegate = self
  self.textEntry = UITextField()
  self.titleLabel.text = self.titleText

  if self.titleText != "Enter Name" {
    self.textEntry.hidden = true
  }
}
```

The title text is set elsewhere, and most definitely displays as it should, but the text field doesn't go away. I've tried putting the if statement in the same place where the titleText is set but it doesn't seem to work there either.

Answer (score 0):

I this the problem is with setting the delegate.

Please set textfield delegate to your ViewController like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {
```

and then create the IBOutlet for your text field like this

```
@IBOutlet var txtTest : UITextField = nil
```

make sure that it is connected to your text field on your view in storyboard.

finally set its delegate using

```
txtTest.delegate=self
```

We are almost done. Now place this delegate function into your class.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField!) -> Bool // called when 'return' key pressed. return NO to ignore.
    {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true;
    }
```

Hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: I've got everything set up the way you have it there except for setting the IBOutlet variable to nil, and I can't actually do that without introducing a whole host of errors.